# How to amplify a signal from a function generator from 5V to 35V?

Tags: voltage, amplifier, transformer, function-generator, voltage-controlled-amplifier

I have a function generator that has an output voltage of 10Vpp. I need to use it to drive a voice-coil-actuator (VCA) that operates on 35V and 11.7A.

I was searching for a solution to amplify the signal from the function generator to reach the required operating volt. Any ideas how to achieve this task? Can I use a transformer instead of  an amplifier?

Comment: Buy a 400W Class D audio DC power Amp or motor controller

Comment: Does Audio amp support the frequency range of VCA that is somewhere between 0~120 Hz?

Comment: define power source , not a transformer

Comment: I do not understand. Excuse me but I am not an electrical engineer. Could you explain your comment?

Comment: The VCA is a V/I= 3 ohm load similar to subwoofer amps, yet those typically do not go down to DC. Your need to say what is your input power source available and go shopping. There is no cheap solution.

Comment: We have a big vibration table that uses 4 VCAs and a pair of two-channel rackmount audio amplifiers.  As far as I can tell, the amps are completely off the shelf and unmodified.  The big caveat is that you are limited by the lowest reproducible frequency of your amplifier which is, as mentioned, typically not zero.

Comment: @vir, actually I am trying to construct a shaker using a linear guide and a VCA. So, what you say is that any amp will do work with the VCA?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily think any amp would work since they're not really designed for that application.  You might have to do some experimentation to see what works, remembering that specifications for audio equipment (specifically power) should be taken with a grain of salt.  The amps we have are Crown DSi 1000s.

Comment: @Tony, let me get it straight, do you mean that I need to connect one of those amps found in this video "https://youtu.be/l8xJivIWZlU?t=97" that has a power IV=400W with a 48V DC power supply and connect the function generator as input then connect the output to the VCA instead of the subwoofer shown in the video.

Comment: @vir, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Sub-amps are rarely DC coupled. The Crown DC amp is a good choice, but not cheap. It is rated 500W/ch into 4 ohms, not 3, but close